# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog having to quit twice

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I have a JOptionPane that appears when a certain condition isn't met and for some reason when I press "Ok" it appears again, but then when pressing "Ok" on the second dialog it goes way.

Below is the method where the dialog gets made:

```
public boolean checkBet()
{
    if(currentPlayer.getBet() <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must place a bet before you can roll your dice!.",
                "Bet Required!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

and this is where the above method gets called:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    checkBet();
    if(checkBet())
    {
        setRollingPlayer(currentPlayer);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameEngine.rollPlayer(rollingPlayer, 500, 2000, 500);
            }
        }.start();  
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You're call `checkBet` twice in the `actionPerformed` method

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    checkBet(); // Here
    if(checkBet()) // And here
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling function `checkBet()` in `actionPerformed()`, it has been mentioned two times. Function `checkBet()` will also execute inside `if()`.

Remove calling once and it will execute once.